# Standard error of estimate of $\lambda^2$

Tags: unbiased-estimator, point-estimation

In a problem, given $n$ observations from $Poisson(\lambda)$ , I have to get an unbiased estimator of $\lambda ^2 $ and the corresponding standard error.

I used the efficiency test to get the unbiased estimator as $( \bar x ^2 - \bar x / n)$ where $\bar x$ is the sample mean.

I am unable to understand how to calculate the standard error of the estimate. For the mean, I know it's $sqrt( \lambda/n)$

How to calculate the standard error of any estimate?